# How pass parameters from urlA to urlB without show them in the url

Tags: angular, router, angular-router, angular-activatedroute

I need to pass parameters from URLA o urlB whithout and the urlB must be show ( so I can't use `skiplocation=true`).

in my ts I do ( in URLA) :

```
 this.router.navigate([URLB], {
                queryParams:
                {
                    name: "erika"

                }
            });
```

and when I take the parameter I do:

```
 this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.name = params['name'];

    });
```

The proble is that it shows me url in this way `URLB?name=erika` and I don't want to do this, but i want the it show me `URLB` and I can take parameters. Anyone can help me?

Comment: If you are sending queryparams programmatically, Why you dont use service/input instead of using queryParams. If you use service you can store that data in service and fetch it from any of the component. or you can use event emitters to send data to a particular component.

Comment: `Service` is a best option to do that . You can use `localstorage` also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
let data = {name: 'erika'}
this.router.navigateByUrl([URLB], data);
```

and this:

```
this.activatedRoute.data
  .subscribe(
    (data: Data) => {
      this.name = data['name'];
    }
  );
```

Comment: I'm tring to use your solution and when I so this this.router.navigateByUrl('/urlB',data). The compiler it gives me this error "data has no properties in common with type 'NavigationExtras'"

Comment: a good explain, in: https://netbasal.com/set-state-object-when-navigating-in-angular-7-2-b87c5b977bb

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways to achieve that.

1) Share data through [@Input](https://theappraisallane.atlassian.net/browse/RT-4598) and [@Output](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)

2) Sharing data through a service:
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

3) Sharing data through State libraries. I recommend you [Ngxs](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use @Input to pass data from one component to another without the need to see this data reflected in the url

More information https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction